# Jolt shift spec where output key is input value

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

simplified input

```
{
  "controllerServiceReferencingComponents": [
    {
      "revision": {
        "version": 5
      },
      "component": {
        "id": "9c050865-6d3a-3bb4-1ec5-b02fdfb103d1"
      }
    },
    {
      "revision": {
        "version": 1
      },
      "component": {
        "id": "a6ac00ee-0173-1000-24c9-70d812e16108"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

desired output

```
{
  "referencingComponentRevisions": {
    "9c050865-6d3a-3bb4-1ec5-b02fdfb103d1": {
      "version": 5
    },
    "a6ac00ee-0173-1000-24c9-70d812e16108": {
      "version": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I want to use the **values** of `controllerServiceReferencingComponents.component.id` in the input as the **keys** of `referencingComponentRevisions`

I have tried variations around

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "controllerServiceReferencingComponents": {
        "*": {
          "component": {
            "id": "referencingComponentRevisions."
          },
          "revision": {
            "clientId": "referencingComponentRevisions.&.clientID"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

as my spec but, I end up with outputs like

```
{
  "referencingComponentRevisions" : [ "9c050865-6d3a-3bb4-1ec5-b02fdfb103d1", "a6ac00ee-0173-1000-24c9-70d812e16108" ]
}
```

where the value of `referencingComponentRevisions` ends up being an array not an object

FWIW I'm trying to do this within a NiFi JoltTransformJSON Processor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with simple shifts,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "controllerServiceReferencingComponents": {
        "*": {
          "component": {
            "@(1,revision.version)": "referencingComponentRevisions.@(1,id).version"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```